# how to optimize the inner query?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT mark.student_id,
          .
          .
          .
          MAX(mark.SAVE_TIME) AS SAVE_TIME,
          (SELECT tamil FROM mark WHERE SAVE_TIME = (MAX(mark.SAVE_TIME))) AS tamilmark,
          (SELECT english FROM mark WHERE SAVE_TIME = (MAX(mark.SAVE_TIME))) AS englishmark
   FROM
   (.......
   )
```

Above query will return the my expected data. but the problem is two times I'm fetching the data from same table. How can i achieve with single select statement?

Comment: I only see two different tables in your query. Anwyay why would it be a problem?

Comment: sorry updated it

Comment: Your full query, along with sample data and expected result would be great.

Comment: Why do you think it's a problem ? If you look at the query plan it's quite possible it smart enough to do it only once.

Comment: I'm sorry I should not give those details. That's my situation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, because two times i'm firing the query with diff columns.

Suppose if it can be achieved in signle query then it is fine.

Comment: So you want us to fix a problem, without seeing the full problem, and without any examples...?

Comment: No.... you're submitting one query and the query plan decides exactly how it will be executed.

Comment: Make sure to use table alias. `SAVE_TIME` could either be from the outer `mark` or the inner `mark` inside the subquery and you don't want to leave the decision to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that could be rewritten:

```
SELECT MySubTable.*, mark.tamil, mark.english
(
SELECT student_id,
          MAX(mark.SAVE_TIME) AS SAVE_TIME
   FROM Table
 GROUP BY student_id
) MySubTable
INNER JOIN mark
ON mark.SAVE_TIME = MySubTable.SAVE_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one select statement to get all values, but you also will get NULLs (in my example I gave them 'n/a' value). To get rid of them you will have to select this subquery:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT mark.student_id,
                MAX(MARK.SAVE_TIME) OVER() AS SAVE_TIME,
                CASE WHEN SAVE_TIME = (MAX(mark.SAVE_TIME) OVER()) THEN tamil ELSE 'n/a' END AS tamilmark,
                CASE WHEN SAVE_TIME = (MAX(mark.SAVE_TIME) OVER()) THEN english ELSE 'n/a' END AS englishmark      
        FROM   MARK
   ) AS t
    WHERE tamilmark != 'n/a'
```